# PC Boots to grub> prompt after putting partition table entries in disk order

Tags: grub, centos

I am using Centos 6.5.  I tried to get the disk space using

```
fdisk -l | grep Disk
```

What I got was

```
Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

I tried to fix the problem with the method outlined [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-fdisk/).  I rebooted the PC but it doesn't go to CentOS.  It just goes to the

```
 grub>
```

prompt which has the form

```
GNU GRUB version 0.97 (639K lower / 1039296K upper memory)

[Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.  For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists possible completions of a device/filename.]
```

Comment: Gah. If you found & followed that article from Googling - you could consider this a warning about the reliability of random relevant sources. I can't imagine what the point of that article is; it doesn't really provide anything over the built-in help from fdisk

Comment: Oh dear. “Partition table entries are not in disk order” isn't a problem. At least it isn't a problem with Linux; I think that fdisk displays this warning because there's some oddball OS somewhere that cares, but most don't. On the other hand, moving or renumbering partitions is a delicate business and can (and did) break your system. You can recover, but you need to know what you're doing. Morale 1: don't try to fix problems that don't exist. Morale 2: when you see something on some random web page, look for confirmation from a reliable source.

Comment: @Gilles.  That's handy to know.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gah.  If you found & followed that article from Googling - you could consider this a warning about the reliability of random relevant sources.  I can't imagine what the point of that article is; it doesn't really provide anything over the built-in help from `fdisk`.

This shows GRUB failed to load its config from the boot partition (due to the number of the partition being changed).  It must sometimes have been possible to use the `grub>` prompt to achieve something, but it'd take a while to work out & IME often can't work, so in general...

http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ReinstallGRUB manually.  You will need to boot from your CentOS install disk.

Less confusingly, from the old docs - this omits the unexplained "Mount all filesystems in read-write mode" above - so perhaps it's not actually necessary.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-boot.html#s2-rescuemode-boot-reinstall-bootloader

> Type linux rescue at the installation boot prompt to enter the rescue environment.  *(But "for CentOS-6 pick "Rescue installed system" from the boot menu.")*
>
> Type chroot /mnt/sysimage to mount the root partition.
>
> Type /sbin/grub-install /dev/hda to reinstall the GRUB boot loader, where /dev/hda is the boot partition.  *(Uh, it does means drive, not partition.  It's more likely to be sda now)*
>
> Review the /boot/grub/grub.conf file, as additional entries may be needed for GRUB to control additional operating systems.
>
> Reboot the system.

In your case you need to update grub.conf with the new partition number.  GRUB uses a different format to Linux; sda... corresponds to (hd0,...).

Comment: It mounted the root partition on /mnt/sysimage before it went to the shell.  However, there is no /sbin/grub-install.  Thanks,

Comment: There is also no /boot.  There is a /mnt/sysimage/boot.  Thanks,

Comment: did you miss the chroot step?

Comment: I'm now OK up to "Review the /boot/grub/grub.conf file,".  I can get into the file with vi.  Is there a resource to say what additional entries are needed?  Thanks,

Comment: Ah, you probably don't need that.  It's more relevant to the case where you install Windows, it overwrites GRUB, and you need to reinstall GRUB *and* add a GRUB entry for Windows.

Comment: I also just realized I don't know if grub.conf on your CentOS includes hard-coded partition numbers (which would need to be updated), or if it will just refer to the filesystem UUID.  Sorry.

Comment: When I try to reboot, it start to start up CentOS but I get the message "Error 15: File not found".  I have 4 CentOS bootup options but they all give that error.  Thanks,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16156/discussion-between-sourcejedi-and-otagoharbour).

Comment: The partition numbers had changed.  I changed all the (hda, 2)s to (hda, 1) and that got me past the original problem.  I also had to change "/dev/sda4 /tmp ext4 noatime,nodiratime,noexec 0 3" in /etc/fstab to /dev/sda3 /tmp ext4 noatime,nodiratime,noexec 0 3 to avoid CentOS crashing with "Checking filesystems /dev/sda4 Could this be a zero length partition?" on start up.